# Adding button into UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I am trying to add button into my table cell like below:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 ....
 UIButton* buttonCheckbox = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        buttonCheckbox.frame = CGRectMake(0, 177, 56, 26);
        buttonCheckbox.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [buttonCheckbox addTarget:self action:@selector(actionFirst1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        [buttonCheckbox setTitle:@"MyTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [cell addSubview:buttonCheckbox];
```

but actionFirst1 event is not fired. if i add the button `[self.view addSubview:buttonCheckbox]` instead of `[cell addSubview:buttonCheckbox]` it works fine. why?

thanks...

Comment: Usually your action method would have a sender parameter (id), in that case the selector would be `@selector(actionFirst1:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try below code it may help you out:

```
if ([indexPath row] == 0) 
    {
                  UIButton *myButton = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, 
                                        heigth)];
        [cell addSubview:myButton];
        cell.accessoryView = myButton;
        [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector (actionFirst1) 
                                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
           }
```

This code will help you out. Please set frames according to your cell of TableView.

Answer (score 2):

You should add this button to the `contentView` property of your cell

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:buttonCheckbox];
```

In fact, all your custom elements inside a `UITableViewCell` should be placed inside the `contentView` as this cell elements (`contentView`, `accessorView` and `image`) are all placed on top of any elements that your cell have.

Check [this doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW11) for more info on cell about custom `UITableviewCell`

Comment: can you place the code for your selector `actionFirst1`? If it has a parameter, like `-(void) actionFirst1:(UIButton *)sender` it is not going to work, as you are sending without any parameter

Answer (score 1):

Please see whether it would suffice to add your button as the accessoryView of the table cell.  In that case, the iOS framework will position the button in the right place for your cell style itself (though you still need to give it a size).  Here's an example from one of my projects:

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 27);  // only size matters
[myButton setTitle:@"Connect" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(connect:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.accessoryView = myButton;
```

That's it.  You just create the control, make sure it has a size, and set it to the accessoryView.